# Gitlab Runner fails with ERROR: Job failed (system failure): Internal error occurred: connection reset by peer

Tags: docker, gitlab, google-kubernetes-engine

I get this error from time to time when running builds with my dedicated runners, running on GKE.

What could be the problem here? 
Is it related to the Gitlab instance or is it more a problem on the cluster side?

`ERROR: Job failed (system failure): Internal error occurred: error executing command in container: error during connect: Get http://%!F(MISSING)var%!F(MISSING)run%!F(MISSING)docker.sock/v1.27/exec/f9ee0d021b8a6d7660d2334456a93f61108835077574545bcf00a484b45f5247/json: read unix @->/var/run/docker.sock: read: connection reset by peer`

Answer (score 0):

See the same thing randomly. There are some jobs more likely than others to trigger it but a retry usually works fine